# What is wrong with my sub-function definition of sinc?

Tags: fortran

```
  implicit     none
  character*20 fflname,oflname
  integer      length_sgnl
  real*8       pi, dt, m, n, theta
  parameter    ( length_sgnl=11900, dt=0.01d0, m=1, n=1, pi=3.1416
 &            ,theta=0.2 )
  integer      i     
  complex*16   cj, coeff ,sgnl(1 : length_sgnl)
  real*8       t(1 : length_sgnl)
  parameter    ( cj = dcmplx(0, 1) )
  real*8       time, real_sgnl, imag_sgnl



  oflname="filtered.data"
  fflname="artificial"
  open(11, file = oflname)
  do i=1, length_sgnl
     read(11, *) time, real_sgnl, imag_sgnl
     sgnl(i) = dcmplx(real_sgnl, imag_sgnl)
     t(i) = (i*dt - m) / (2**n)
  enddo


  coeff = 0
  do i=1, length_sgnl
     coeff = coeff 
 &        + sgnl(i) * sinc (t(i)) * exp (-cj*2*pi*t(i))
  enddo

  do i=1, length_sgnl
     sgnl(i) = sgnl(i) 
 &         - coeff * sinc (t(i)) * exp (-cj*2*pi*t(i))
 &         + coeff * sinc (t(i)) * exp (-cj*2*pi*t(i))
 &         * exp (cj*theta)
  enddo


  open(12, file = fflname)
  do i=1, length_sgnl
    write(12, *) i*dt, sgnl(i)
  enddo
  close(12)


  real*8     function sinc (a)
             real*8 :: sinc, a
             if (abs(a) < 1.0d-6) then
                sinc = 1
             else
                sinc = sin(pi*a) / (pi*a)
             end if
  end function           

  stop
  end
```

---

At the last part of a sub-defined function sinc, I assume the problem is there but I am not sure what it is exactly. The gfortran noticed that I did not define sinc and a, and the "end function" should be "end program"?

Comment: Please add the exact messages from the compiler.  I'll note though that you have at least two problems: a missing `contains` statement; `sinc` is declared twice.  You can probably find questions here about both.

Comment: Also, consider familiarizing yourself with the syntax of Fortran. http://www.fortran90.org/ and http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Tutorials have pointers to such references.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to update your program into standards-compliant modern Fortran:

```
program sinctest
  use :: iso_fortran_env
  implicit none

  ! Declare parameters
  integer,         parameter :: length_sgnl=11900
  real(real64),    parameter :: pi=3.1416, dt=0.01, m=1, n=1, theta=0.2
  complex(real64), parameter :: cj = cmplx(0, 1)

  ! Declare variables
  character(len=20) :: fflname, oflname
  complex(real64)   :: coeff, sgnl(length_sgnl)
  real(real64)      :: time, real_sgnl, imag_sgnl, t(length_sgnl)
  integer           :: i, ofl, ffl

  ! Define filenames
  oflname="filtered.data"
  fflname="artificial"

  ! Read the input file
  open(newunit = ofl, file = oflname)
  do i=1, length_sgnl
     read(ofl, *) time, real_sgnl, imag_sgnl
     sgnl(i) = cmplx(real_sgnl, imag_sgnl, kind=real64)
     t(i) = (i*dt - m) / (2**n)
  end do
  close(ofl)

  ! Process the input signal
  coeff = 0
  do i=1, length_sgnl
     coeff = coeff &
           + sgnl(i) * sinc(t(i)) * exp(-cj*2*pi*t(i))
  end do

  do i=1, length_sgnl
     sgnl(i) = sgnl(i)                              &
          - coeff * sinc(t(i)) * exp(-cj*2*pi*t(i)) &
          + coeff * sinc(t(i)) * exp(-cj*2*pi*t(i)) &
          * exp(cj*theta)
  end do

  ! Save the output file
  open(newunit = ffl, file = fflname)
  do i=1, length_sgnl
    write(ffl, *) i*dt, sgnl(i)
  enddo
  close(ffl)

contains
  pure function sinc(a) result(r)
    ! This function calculates sinc(a)=sin(pi*a)/(pi*a).
    real(real64), intent(in) :: a
    real(real64)             :: r

    if (abs(a) < 1.0e-6) then
      r = 1
    else
      r = sin(pi*a) / (pi*a)
    end if
  end function           
end program
```

To compile it using e.g. GFortran:

```
gfortran -std=f2008 -ffree-form sinctest.f
```

These are the syntax errors that I fixed:

- Added a `contains` section before defining your sinc-function;
- Moved your continuation characters (`&`) from the beginning of a continued line to the end of the previous line;

These are not required changes, just merely style suggestions:

- Used the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env` to get the `real64` variable, which lets you define variables as `real(real64)` instead of `real*8`, as the former is portable while the latter is not;
- Merged the specification of the variable type (e.g. `real`) and `parameter` into a single lines;
- Used the Fortran2008 `newunit` argument to `open` instead of hard-coding in unit numbers, as this saves you some headache if you write large programs and have a modern compiler;
- Made sure that you close the input file as well;
- Declared your sinc-function to be `pure`, as it has no side-effects;
- Used the `result` notation for your sinc-function, so that you don't have to specify the type `real*8` in front of the function name;
- Rewrote the program in the form `program...end program` instead of `...stop end`.

**EDIT:**

I also wanted to note that using modern Fortran, the math itself can be written considerably more consise using 'array notation' and 'elemental functions'. For instance, if you define your sinc-function:

```
   elemental function sinc(a) result(r)
     ! This function calculates sinc(a)=sin(pi*a)/(pi*a).
     real(real64), intent(in) :: a
     real(real64)             :: r

     if (abs(a) < 1.0e-6) then
       r = 1
     else
       r = sin(pi*a) / (pi*a)
     end if
   end function
```

Then the `elemental` keyword says that if you apply the sinc-function to an array, it should return a new array where the sinc-function has been evaluated for each element. So this piece of code:

```
   coeff = 0
   do i=1, length_sgnl
      coeff = coeff &
            + sgnl(i) * sinc(t(i)) * exp(-cj*2*pi*t(i))
   end do
```

Can then actually be written as a one-liner:

```
coeff = sum(sgnl * sinc(t) * exp(-2*pi*cj*t))
```

So I would highly recommend that you look into the modern array notation too :).

**EDIT 2:**
Tried to emphasize what changes are relevant to fixing errors, and what changes are just style suggestions (thanks Vladimir F).

Comment: Your answer is good, I would just somehow emphasize more, what is the solution to the problem (syntax error) and what are just style suggestions. It is a bit lost in this large amount of information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion — I've tried to update the answer accordingly :).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed help and suggestion. Happy Valentine's Day!